# htaccess redirect if URL is bad - how to do this?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect the links which are bad, getting 404 errors.
Let's say I have the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/foobar
```

If the above url is bad, I want it to redirect it with .html suffix

```
http://www.example.com/foobar.html
```

So basically I want to make sure URL is bad and it doesn't end with .html, then only apply the rule, which is same URL with .html suffix.

UPDATE: It's not just `foobar.html`, there are thousands of pages dynamic, so simple use of `/foobar.html` to redirect will not work.

### Examples of what i am looking for

below url will go to standard 404 page

```
http://www.example.com/this-is-bad.html
```

below url will go to it's .html page

```
http://www.example.com/this-is-bad
```

below url will not redirect, because of slash at end

```
http://www.example.com/foobar/
```

below url is working and SHOULD NOT get redirected anywhere. This is not a file but a dynamic page.

```
http://www.example.com/this-is-good
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ErrorDocument 404`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /foobar.html
```

If you want full redirect (change URL in broser) then useL

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/foobar.html
```

This sill redirect all 404 URLs to `/foobar.html`

**UPDATE:** Try this rule

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ /$1.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: no i can't.. as `foobar` can be anything and again it can be leading 404 which should be redirected to proper 404 page.

Comment: True foobar can be anything and this is not just for `foobar` or `blablabla` it will redirect for every 404 condition.

Comment: So you want to redirect `blablabla` to `/blablabla.html` when 404 occurs?

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. See **UPDATE** part now.

Comment: Yes I understood that and updated my answer accordingly. Check UPDATE section of my answer.

Comment: No it also changes `foobar/` with `foobar.html`.. there are some real links which ends in slash but without .html, which are also affected

Comment: So you want a silent rewrite only? In your question you have written that you want redirect?

Comment: sorry i don't know what is silent rewrite. but yes, only if there is no slash, there is no .html behind the url and url should be bad to apply this rule.

Comment: sorry but now .html is not getting appended to bad urls.. previously it was working, but slashes were not working.. now slashes are working

Comment: oh sorry I got confused and removed `R` flag to make it a silent rewrite. Try it now.

Comment: yes but `http://www.example.com/this-is-good` fails now.. it appends .html to the working non-.html urls also thus making them 404

Comment: If `/this-is-good` is a valid file then above redirect shouldn't happen since I am using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` Are you sure `/this-is-good` is a valid file?

Comment: True it a valid page but is it a valid file/dir also? I mean do you have a file or dir named `/this-is-good` ? If NOT then above rule will trigger on this URI also. I suspect this 404 is coming from some PHP/CMA framework not an Apache 404

Comment: yes it's not a valid file, but dynamically generated from php. isn't there a way to check if it's valid then no rewrite?

Comment: What should be the logic to guess its a valid page?

Comment: Actually in this official doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond there is no variable called status code.